# I am trying to add link for react slick, but none of the links I tried worked

Tags: reactjs

[Picture of How I am Using Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMeFI.png)

[Picture of The Links Which I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bobVC.png)
[picture of The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRjmY.png)

..Trying to get the right link

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your indextest.html file it seems like you're missing attribute(s) in your link tag.

Try replacing your link tag with this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css"/>
```

Based on the error message its saying that react-slick is not installed or probably not imported correctly. From looking at your Slider.js file, I'm not sure how your codes are being structured but it seems like you're missing several **imports**:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Slider from "react-slick";
```

For a clearer guide you can try following the steps in their documentation: [quick-start](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/get-started) guide from react-slick.